# Is possible to Install Android in other phone? Like the SH004 or other OEM Phones

Tags: android, mobile

I'm wondering if is possible to install/use Android with other phones? Will be nice to have it on such a piece of hardware like the new SH004.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile phones are generally **very** hardware independent of each other and require a serious amount of hacking in order to do any sort of "moding".

I can barely find any information on the SH004, but I think it will have to be out for a few months before you will even start to hear people of moding it, yet alone installing another Operating system.

Your best bet is to find specialised forums such as [CellPhoneHacks](http://www.cellphonehacks.com/), (There are better around, but not sure if I should link to).

Answer (score 0):

Android is actually designed to be portable, and to provide source code for most of the generic pieces.  However, the possibility of running it on a consumer device intended for a different operating system/framework depends on three things:

1) The hardware must have sufficient capability - likely meaning it was originally designed to have comparable capabilities under whatever OS it shipped with.

2) Sufficient low-level documentation must be published or reverse engineered to adapt a Linux kernel, flash memory driver, user I/O drivers (touchscreen, etc), and anything communication related (wifi, mobile, etc) and optionally any extras (accelerometer, gps, etc)

3) It must be possible, either by design or by finding an exploit, to run arbitrary code on the device - ie, boot an image which has not been signed by an approved party such as the OEM.